# Array.forEach Updating each Item in Array on click

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, javascript-objects

When the program runs the mouse is clicked creating a projectile from the center of the screen moving with every frame in the direction it was fired (mouse position on click).

When N+1 projectiles have fired all projectiles on-screen move to the new clicked location instead of continuing their path.

I am can not figure out why the current projectiles change direction when the New projectile's velocity should have no effect on prior projectiles.

index.html

```
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="./guns.js"></script>
<script src="./indexh.js"></script>
<script src="./runh.js"></script>
```

runh.html

```
const projectilesArray = [];
let frameCount = 0;

function animate() {
    animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    projectilesArray.forEach((Projectile, pIndex) => {
        Projectile.update();
        console.log(Projectile)
  
        if (
          Projectile.x + Projectile.radius < 0 ||
          Projectile.x - Projectile.radius > canvas.width ||
          Projectile.y + Projectile.radius < 0 ||
          Projectile.y - Projectile.radius > canvas.height
        ) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            projectilesArray.splice(pIndex, 1);
          }, 0);
        }
      });
    
    frameCount++;
    if (frameCount > 150) {
        
    }
}
var fire = 1;
let fireRate = 1;
const mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    click: true,
  };

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {

    if (fire % fireRate == 0) {
      if (mouse.click == true) {
        mouse.x = event.x;
        mouse.y = event.y;

        const angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y - (canvas.height / 2), mouse.x - (canvas.width / 2));
        const fireY = Math.sin(angle);
        const fireX = Math.cos(angle);
        //score -= 0;
        //scoreL.innerHTML = score;
        var weapon = new Projectile(cannon);
        weapon.velocity.x = fireX * 9;
        weapon.velocity.y = fireY * 9;
       
        projectilesArray.push(weapon);
     

        //var gun = object.constructor()
      }
    }
  });

  animate();
```

indexh.js

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;



class Projectile {
    constructor(config) {
        this.color = config.color || "rgb(60, 179, 113)";
        this.radius = config.radius || 1;
        this.speed = config.speed || 5;
        this.rounds = config.rounds || 2;
        this.x = config.x || canvas.width / 2;
        this.y = config.y || canvas.height /2;
        this.velocity = config.velocity;
    }
    draw() {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fill();
    }
    update() {
        this.draw();
        this.x = this.x + this.velocity.x * this.speed;
        this.y = this.y + this.velocity.y * this.speed;
    }
}
```

gums.js

```
let pistol = {
    color : "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    radius : 10,
    speed : 1,
    rounds : 1,

    velocity : {
        x: 1,
        y: 1
    }
}

let cannon = {
    color : "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
    radius : 30,
    speed : .5,
    rounds : 1,

    velocity : {
        x: 1,
        y: 1
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you create a JSFiddle with your code and share it

Comment: What does `N+1` mean?  Also, I see a bug at the line `projectilesArray.splice(pIndex, 1);`  A bunch of those timeouts can be queued at once, and then they will remove the wrong index.  I don't think that's the issue you posted about though.

Comment: You could try commenting that `projectilesArray.splice(pIndex, 1);` line out for now.  It means your projectiles will fly off forever, but it's just to see if that's your problem.

Comment: N+1 is the number of projectiles on screen, so any more than one. 


JSFiddle. I will do that in the future. 

Thanks for bug find on the splice. Will be looking into that today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have this cannon object used as a configuration object:

```
let cannon = {
    color : "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
    radius : 30,
    speed : .5,
    rounds : 1,

    velocity : {
        x: 1,
        y: 1
    }
}
```

And in your `Projectile` constructor you assign `this.velocity = config.velocity;`  You are assigning `this.velocity` to be the same object instance for all `Projectile`s.  To fix it, try copying the object, like:

```
this.velocity = {...config.velocity};
```

That will make a copy of the object rather than sharing the same object instance.

Also note that you have a bug that you didn't ask about in this line:

```
projectilesArray.splice(pIndex, 1);
```

If two timeouts are queued in the same loop, the array will shift when the first timeout fires, and the second timeout will be operating on the wrong index.

Comment: This worked, I will have to do some research into the
 ```projectilesArray.splice(pIndex, 1); 
``` 
The new Projectile constructor is as follows. 
```
class Projectile {
    constructor(config) {
        ...
        //this.velocity = config.velocity;
        this.velocity = {
            x : config.velocity.x,
            y : config.velocity.y
        }
    }```
Take my upvote… I don’t have high enough activity on here, but I clicked it, Thanks

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept it as the answer!  One solution to the `splice` issue is to set the entry in the array to `undefined` (no `setTimeout`), and after the loop, do something like `projectilesArray = projectilesArray.filter(p => p)` (make the array non-const).

Comment: Thanks, I marked it as solved. And thanks for the input for the splice.